# C - Inconsistent Data from Socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, posix

I've got a simple proxy server program written in C for a course. I'm having some issues with inconsistent data. When I request the website, I save the resulting data in a file on the server side, then send it over to the client and save it on the client side as well. The results on both the client and server will be of different sizes and it appears that some of the HTML is being duplicated. Typically, the file saved on the server will be smaller than the one saved on the client, although both files are still larger than the actual web page (i.e., if I were to right click the page and 'save as', the resulting page is smaller than those returned by my code). I've tried various things to resolve this issue and nothing seems to work. The results even seem to differ between attempts at the same website. For instance, I can request the same website twice, yet the file sizes differ from both attempts. In very rare occasions, especially on small websites, both the client and server program return the correct web page and both files are of the appropriate size.

Note: I'm aware that the code is still rather messy. I'm more worried about addressing this issue before I move any further. I will address issues (such as checking if the socket failed to open) once this issue is corrected, so please only address the issue I have outlined.

Server.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <time.h>

/*Code used to resolve URL into IP address adapted from following URL:
http://www.binarytides.com/hostname-to-ip-address-c-sockets-linux/
*/

//This code has been adapted from the server code provided in class

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char str[655360];
    char recvline[655360];
    char parsedRecv[655360];
    char domain[1025];
    char directory[1025];
    char absoluteURL[1025];
    char temp[1025];


    int listen_fd, conn_fd, n, tempCount;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    int bytesRead;
    int stringCounter;

    int port;

    FILE *fp;

    //Variables used for second socket and resolving of host
    char ip[100];
    int sockfd, secondSocketCount;
    int len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    struct sockaddr_in secondServaddr;
    struct addrinfo *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_in *h;
    int rv;
    char simpleMatch[10];
    int flag = 0;
    //End

    //Used for HTTP GET request
    char request[2049];

    listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Error! Enter a port number to run this server on.\n\tEx: ./server 22000\n\r\0");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        port = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);

    printf("\n");
    printf("Awaiting connections...\n");

    bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    listen(listen_fd, 10);

    //Once the server is listening, enter an infinite loop to keep listening
    while(1)
    {
        conn_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr*) NULL, NULL);
        bytesRead = read(conn_fd, recvline, sizeof(recvline));
        if(bytesRead > 0) //data read
        {
            recvline[bytesRead] = '\0';

            bzero(absoluteURL, 1025);
            strcpy(absoluteURL, recvline);

            //Extract host and page from recvline
            //For loop used to check if URL begins with HTTP or HTTPS
            for(stringCounter = 0; stringCounter < 5; stringCounter++)
            {
                simpleMatch[stringCounter] = tolower(recvline[stringCounter]);
            }
            simpleMatch[strlen(simpleMatch)] = '\0';
            if(strcmp("http:", simpleMatch) == 0)
            {
                for(stringCounter = 7, tempCount = 0; stringCounter < strlen(recvline); stringCounter++, tempCount++)
                {
                    temp[tempCount] = recvline[stringCounter];
                }
                temp[strlen(temp)] = '\0';
                strcpy(recvline, temp);
            }
            else if(strcmp("https", simpleMatch) == 0)
            {
                for(stringCounter = 8, tempCount = 0; stringCounter < strlen(recvline); stringCounter++, tempCount++)
                {
                    temp[tempCount] = recvline[stringCounter];
                }
                temp[strlen(temp)] = '\0';
                strcpy(recvline, temp);
            }

            //printf("\n\nAfter stripping HTTP, we are left with: %s\n\n", recvline);

            //Now that HTTP:// or HTTPS:// has been stripped, can parse for domain
            for(stringCounter = 0, tempCount = 0; stringCounter < strlen(recvline); stringCounter++)
            {
                //moving domain into the domain string
                if(flag == 0)
                {
                    if(recvline[stringCounter] != '/')
                    {
                        domain[stringCounter] = recvline[stringCounter];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        domain[stringCounter + 1] = '\0';
                        //directory[tempCount] = recvline[stringCounter];
                        flag = 1;
                        tempCount++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    directory[tempCount] = recvline[stringCounter];
                    tempCount++;
                }
            }

            //printf("\n\nDirectory is: %s\n\n", directory);

            //reset flag and append '\0' to directory and domain
            flag = 0;
            if(tempCount < 1025)
            {
                directory[tempCount] = '\0';
            }
            //directory[strlen(directory)] = '\0';
            //domain[strlen(domain)] = '\0';

            //Done extracting

            //Resolve hostname to IP

            if((rv = getaddrinfo(domain, NULL, NULL, &servinfo)) != 0)
            {
                printf("Error: an IP address cannot be resolved for %s\n", domain);
                return 0;
                //fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
            }
            else
            {
                for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
                {
                    h = (struct sockaddr_in *) p->ai_addr;
                    strcpy(ip, inet_ntoa(h->sin_addr));
                }

                freeaddrinfo (servinfo);

                printf("%s resolved to: %s\n", domain, ip);
            }
            //End Resolve

            //Now that the IP is resolved, open a socket and connect to the IP

            //Open socket
            sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
            bzero(&secondServaddr, sizeof(secondServaddr));

            secondServaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            secondServaddr.sin_port = htons(80);

            inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &(secondServaddr.sin_addr)); //IP taken from earlier resolution
            connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &secondServaddr, sizeof(secondServaddr));

            //socket is open, can create and send request, finally
            bzero(request, 2049);
            //sprintf(request, "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n", directory, domain);
            //sprintf(request, "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n", absoluteURL);
            //sprintf(request, "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n", absoluteURL, domain);
            sprintf(request, "GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n", directory, domain);

            write(sockfd, request, strlen(request));

            printf("\tAttempting to retrieve data: this may be slow.\n");

            bzero(recvline, 655360);
            bzero(parsedRecv, 655360);

            //Old method used to retrieve data
            //This was changed when I began to run into issues
            /*while(1)
            {
                secondSocketCount = read(sockfd, parsedRecv, sizeof(parsedRecv));
                if(secondSocketCount == -1)
                {
                    printf("Error receiving data: server terminating.\n");
                    return 0;
                }
                else if(secondSocketCount == 0)
                {
                    //no more data
                    break;
                }
                strcat(recvline, parsedRecv);
            }*/

            //This while loop is used to read in data (the response from the server)
            bzero(str, 655360);
            while(secondSocketCount = read(sockfd, recvline, sizeof(recvline)) > 0)
            {
                strcat(str, recvline);
            }
            //bzero(parsedRecv, 655360);
            //recvline[strlen(recvline)] = '\0';

            printf("\tData retrieved from main server.\n");

            //This for loop finds the end of the HTTP header and copies everything after into parsedRecv
            for(stringCounter = 0, tempCount = 0; stringCounter < strlen(str); stringCounter++)
                {
                    //lazy if statement to find two \r\n in a row to mark the end of the header
                    if(str[stringCounter] == '\r' && str[stringCounter + 1] == '\n' && str[stringCounter + 2] == '\r' && str[stringCounter + 3] == '\n' && flag == 0)
                    {
                        flag = 1;
                        stringCounter += 3;
                    }
                    if(flag == 1)
                    {
                        parsedRecv[tempCount] = str[stringCounter];
                        tempCount++;
                    }
                }
            flag = 0;
            parsedRecv[strlen(parsedRecv)] = '\0';
            fp = fopen("ReturnedPageServer.html", "w");
            if(fp != NULL)
            {
                fprintf(fp, "%s", parsedRecv);
                //fprintf(fp, "%s", recvline);
            }
            fclose(fp);
            printf("\tData saved to ReturnedPageServer.html\n");

        }

        //strcpy(str, "This is a test of the Hello World Broadcast System.\n");
        bzero(str, 655360);
        strcpy(str, parsedRecv);
        write(conn_fd, str, strlen(str));
        close(conn_fd);
        printf("\tData sent to client.\n");
        printf("Awaiting further connections...\n");

        //strcpy(directory, "");
        //strcpy(domain, "");
        //strcpy(recvline, "");
        bzero(directory, 1025);
        bzero(domain, 1025);
        bzero(temp, 1025);
        bzero(recvline, 655360);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Client.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//Code adapted from client code provided in class

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int sockfd, n, port;
    int len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    char sendline[10000];
    char recvline[655360];
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    FILE *fp;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Error! Enter the port number for the server.\n\tEx: ./client 22000\n\r\0");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        port = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);

    inet_pton(AF_INET, "129.120.151.94", &(servaddr.sin_addr)); //CSE01 IP
    connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    printf("url: ");
    scanf("%s", sendline);

    //strcpy(sendline, "The server should display this text.\n\0");
    //printf("\nLength of string: %d\n", strlen(sendline));
    //printf("\t%s\n", sendline);
    write(sockfd, sendline, strlen(sendline));

    fp = fopen("ReturnedPageClient.html", "w");
    bzero(recvline, 655360);
    while(n = read(sockfd, recvline, sizeof(recvline)) > 0)
    {
        //printf("%s", recvline);
        if(fp != NULL)
        {
            fprintf(fp, "%s", recvline);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\tError saving file: client terminating.\n");
            fclose(fp);
            return 0;
        }

    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("\tResponse received from proxy server.\n\tFile saved as \"ReturnedPageClient.html\"\n");
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `simpleMatch[strlen(simpleMatch)] = '\0';` will not null terminate the string!

Comment: You're using `strlen` on things that are not C-style strings. If they're C-style strings, they're already nul terminated. If they're not C-style strings, you can't pass them to `strlen`.

Comment: syntax error: `while(n = read(sockfd, recvline, sizeof(recvline)) > 0)`

Answer (score 2):

one problem - not sure if its 'the problem' - is that you are expecting TCP to be message oriented. I.e. you send a message of , say, 500 bytes and expect to receive one block of 500 bytes. This is not how TCP works . TCP is stream oriented, a 500 byte send can be recevied as 250 2 byte reads on the server , or 1 500 byte or 100, 50, 100, 2,2,2,2,2, 240. You must loop on the server till you receive all of the 'message'. This will lead to inconsistent behavior, in particular things will work locally but not over a 'real' network

This in turn raises the question of how you know that you have received a whole 'message'. You need to have some higher level protocol that allows message framing (like sending a fixed size length then the body)

Comment: Don't we have a good duplicate for this? It's a 3rd question of the  same nature today.

Answer (score 0):

To sequence the communication between the client and server with sockets, you need some sort of protocol so each party in the connection can determine when a message is complete. A message transmitted over a TCP socket can be received in chunks of a different size than what was written by the sending side.

You do not take this into account in your programs, you assume that a successful `read` request with return the data that was written by the `write` request on the sending side.  This is incorrect: you should keep reading from the socket and store the chunks read into a request buffer until a full request is there or the socket is closed.

A simple protocol would be to write one line at a time.  Sequencing requests and answers with `\n` characters.  This is more or less what the HTTP, SMTP and POP protocols do.

The code many problems:

- It has syntax errors that prevent compilation.
- You define very large buffers as automatic variables, in excess of 2MB, you may get a stack overflow on some systems.
- The data that was read into the buffer should be null terminated by hand since you do not transmit the `'\0'` terminators.  You seem to be aware of this problem, but your method `parsedRecv[strlen(parsedRecv)] = '\0';` does not do anything useful. `strlen(parsedRecv)` by definition is the offset of the `'\0'` byte. If the string is not properly null terminated, `strlen` will scan beyond the end of the buffer and invoke undefined behavior. You should just set a `'\0'` byte by hand with `recvline[n] = '\0';` after a successful `read`.
- You try and match string fragments with `strcmp`: this is not the most efficient, since you need to first copy the fragment to a separate buffer and null terminate it so `strcmp` can compare that as a full string.  Use `memcmp` instead with a specified fragment length.